# Как построить диаграмму через matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, график, диаграммы

Есть некоторый код

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import comb

class StatsMethods:


  def mean(x):
    return np.sum(x) / len(x)


  def std(x):
    x_mean = StatsMethods.mean(x)
    n = len(x)
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x - x_mean)**2) / n)


  def var_pop(x):
    x_mean = StatsMethods.mean(x)
    n = len(x)
    return np.sum((x - x_mean)**2) / n


  def var_samp(x):
    x_mean = StatsMethods.mean(x)
    n = len(x)
    return np.sum((x - x_mean)**2) / (n - 1)

numbers = [5, 100, 59, 77, 45]

print(f'Среднее арифметическое: {np.round(StatsMethods.mean(numbers), 4)}')
print(f'Среднее квадратическое отклоненние: {np.round(StatsMethods.std(numbers), 4)}')
print(f'Смещенная дисперсия: {np.round(StatsMethods.var_pop(numbers), 4)}')
print(f'Несмещенная дисперсия: {np.round(StatsMethods.var_samp(numbers), 4)}')
```

И нужно по этим данным построить любую диаграмму

Comment: Как я понял вы выполняете какое-то задание в обучение, поэтмоу вопрос, принципиально использоваться matplotlib?

Comment: что вы понимаете под любой диаграммой?

Comment: именно, argo7. А диаграмму в смысле по данным задания построить диаграмму или график любого типа. Например круговую и т.д.